# How to click the li in the dropdown programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, local-storage

I am a having a custom dropdown in which on the click of the item in the dropdown, top selection text I am changing. But when the user goes forward to the next step and goes back to the current step, I am trying to store in a local storage, And using that id in the local storage .. I want to click the li programmatically. How ever the `click()` function does not work.

```
<div class="btn-group custom-drop" style="display:inline-block;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle drop-width" data-toggle="dropdown"><div class="dropdownValue" style="color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.56);">Choose An Occasion </div><span class="caret"></span></button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
        <li class="bla" id="1"><a icon="birthdayIcon" href="#">Birthday</a></li>
        <li class="bla" id="2"><a icon="weddingIcon" href="#">Wedding</a></li>
        <li class='bla' id="3"><a icon="anniversaryIcon" href="#">Anniversary</a></li>
        <li class='bla' id="4"><a icon="farewellIcon" href="#">Farewell</a></li>
        <li class='bla' id="5"><a icon="thanksGivingIcon" href="#">Thanks giving</a></li>
        <li class='bla' id="6"><a icon="graduationIcon" href="#">Graduation Day</a></li>
        <li class='bla' id="7"><a icon="newYearIcon" href="#">New Year’s Day – January 1</a></li>
        <li class='bla' id="8"><a icon="valentineIcon" href="#">Valentine’s Day – February 14</a></li>
        <li class='bla' id="9"><a icon="womenIcon" href="#">International Women’s Day – March 8</a></li>
        <li class='bla' id="10"><a icon="easterIcon" href="#">Easter – March 27</a></li>
        <li class='bla' id="11"><a icon="motherIcon" href="#">Mother’s Day – May 8</a></li>
        <li class='bla' id="12"><a icon="fatherIcon" href="#">Father’s Day - June 19</a></li>
        <li class='bla' id="13"><a icon="doctorIcon" href="#">Doctor’s Day – July 1</a></li>
        <li class='bla' id="14"><a icon="parentIcon" href="#">Parent’s Day – July 24</a></li>
        <li class='bla' id="15"><a icon="friendIcon" href="#">Friendship Day – August 7</a></li>
        <li class='bla' id="16"><a icon="sdIcon" href="#">Son and Daughter Day – August 11</a></li>
        <li class='bla' id="17"><a icon="teacherIcon" href="#">Teachers Day – September 5</a></li>
        <li class='bla' id="18"><a icon="dussehraIcon" href="#">Dussehra – October 11</a></li>
        <li class='bla' id="19"><a icon="bossIcon" href="#">Boss’s Day – October 17</a></li>
        <li class='bla' id="20"><a icon="diwaliIcon" href="#">Diwali  - October 30</a></li>
        <li class='bla' id="21"><a icon="halloweenIcon" href="#">Halloween – October 31</a></li>
        <li class='bla' id="22"><a icon="childrenIcon" href="#">Children’s Day – November 14</a></li>
        <li class='bla' id="23"><a icon="christmasIcon" href="#">Christmas – December 25</a></li>
        <li class='bla' id="24"><a icon="shijokesIcon" href="#">Just get a Shijokes</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the JS I have

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //persistence for the choose ocdasion
    if(localStorage.getItem('occasion_id')! == 'null'){
        var id_previousclick = localStorage.getItem('occasion_id');
        console.log(id_previousclick);
        $('#'+id_previousclick).click();
    }

    $('.dropdown-menu li').click(function(event){
            $('.dropdownValue').text(event.srcElement.text);
            var iconHolder = $('.iconHolder').removeClass();
            iconHolder.addClass('iconHolder '+ $(event.srcElement).attr('icon'));
            //sending the dropdown id 
            var send_occ = event.srcElement.parentElement.id;
            console.log(send_occ);
            $('.send-occ').val(send_occ);
            localStorage.setItem("occasion_id",parseInt(send_occ));
      });
});
```

Observations I have seen

`$('#2').click()` would not work, that means click is not applicable to li I guess.

Problem I am facing

The if condition currently I have in JS, does not let the item clicked to be displayed on the top of the dropdown. Removing the if condition is making the dropdown clickable and top element is changing.

Comment: Does not work@choz

Comment: I believe click is applicable to li, here's a fiddle that proves it https://jsfiddle.net/sniels/rqx2b4ma/.
The reason it doesn't work is because you trigger the click-event before you attach an event handler to the event. Simply move the event code up.

Comment: use trigger instead of click $("#previusID").trigger('click')

Comment: @sniels. I think you made a good point, yes as per the snippet I have given I am triggering before the event is attached. So the http://pastebin.com/BUTpA5iF should work right? But still it does not work :(

Comment: @gates I noticed it still doesn't work, but that's because there are some other errors inside the event-callback, the callback does get triggered.

Comment: @gates, I also fixed the code inside the callback, see the comment in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, These are the mistakes that I noticed so far.

1. There's a typo here `if(localStorage.getItem('occasion_id')! ==
   'null')`. Fix it to `!==`.
2. `event.srcElement` is undefined. I believe you want to do `$(this)`. So it'd be `$(this).text()` to get the text of the clicked `li`.
3. Same with the 2nd, the `li` doesn't have the `icon attribute`. Its' child does which is `a`. So it would be `$(this).find('a').attr('icon')`
4. Same with the 2nd, `event.srcElement.parentElement.id` to `this.parentElement.id`. I believe you want to select the parent of `li`. But in this case, it will always return `null` unless you define the `id` of the container `ul`.
5. Then you can happily call `$('#2').click()` or with `trigger`.

However, I still haven't noticed what `.iconHolder` is. So, when you assign the class to `iconHolder`, it would not work in this answer.

So finally, this is how it should look like

```
$(function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('occasion_id') !== 'null') {
    var id_previousclick = localStorage.getItem('occasion_id');
    console.log(id_previousclick);
    $('#' + id_previousclick).click();
  }

  $('.dropdown-menu li').click(function(event) {
    $('.dropdownValue').text($(this).text());
    var iconHolder = $('.iconHolder').removeClass();
    iconHolder.addClass('iconHolder ' + $(this).find('a').attr('icon'));

    //sending the dropdown id 
    var send_occ = this.parentElement.id;
    console.log(send_occ);
    $('.send-occ').val(send_occ);
    localStorage.setItem("occasion_id", parseInt(send_occ));
  });

  $("#2").click();
})
```

And the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LLmuam5p/2/)

Comment: the li hasn't got a icon attribute

Comment: @madalinivascu ups, I didn't see the `a` element in it. Thanks for noticing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
function changeEv(el) {
 $('.dropdownValue').text(el.text());
            var iconHolder = $('.iconHolder').removeClass();
            iconHolder.addClass('iconHolder '+ el.find('a').attr('icon'));
}
    //persistence for the choose ocdasion
    if(localStorage.getItem('occasion_id') != 'null'){
        var id_previousclick = localStorage.getItem('occasion_id');
        console.log(id_previousclick);
        changeEv($('#'+id_previousclick))
    }

    $('.dropdown-menu li').click(function(event){
           changeEv($(this))
            //sending the dropdown id 
            var send_occ =  $(this).attr('id');
            console.log(send_occ);
            $('.send-occ').val(send_occ);
            localStorage.setItem("occasion_id",parseInt(send_occ));
      });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/67efmfun/1/

Answer (score 1):

You click the li-element before you attached an event handler, first attach the event handler and then trigger your clicks. I ran the code in the fiddle, and there are some errors, but the click handler is being run.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-menu li').click(function(event) {
    $('.dropdownValue').text(event.srcElement.text);
    var iconHolder = $('.iconHolder').removeClass();
    iconHolder.addClass('iconHolder ' + $(event.srcElement).attr('icon'));
    //sending the dropdown id 
    var send_occ = event.srcElement.parentElement.id;
    console.log(send_occ);
    $('.send-occ').val(send_occ);
    localStorage.setItem("occasion_id", parseInt(send_occ));
  });
  //persistence for the choose ocdasion
  if (localStorage.getItem('occasion_id') ! == 'null') {
    var id_previousclick = localStorage.getItem('occasion_id');
    console.log(id_previousclick);
    $('#' + id_previousclick).click();
  }


});
```

Comment: I also fixed the code inside your event handler: https://jsfiddle.net/sniels/yz0Lz4yb/

Answer (score 0):

try this script.

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click",".bla" , function () {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
        // OR
        // Your next code here
    });
</script>
```

Also this will Work

```
$(document).on("click",".dropdown-menu li" , function () {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: Hi Punit, it's not about the onClick being executed. The code works fine, the dropdown top element text is changing fine with the code I have. But the thing is it breaks, with the introduction of the localStorage if condition . Breaks in the sense, on the click of li itself the top element is not changing @sniels